# Laravel 5 artisan commands time limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to execute an Artisan commands from a Controller like this :

```
$params = [
            'base_id' => $base_id, 
            'file' => \Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName()
        ];
        $import = \Artisan::call('base:add_dest', $params);
```

It does the job for 1 minute maximum and then it gets stopped (I guess because I can see the number of rows inserted and it is not the expected number of rows).

Interestingly, there is no problem while executing from command line :

```
php artisan base:add_dest 1 file.csv
```

I tried to modify the max_execution_time to 0 from php.ini file but no gain.

Any guesses?

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like out of memory issue?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/1568oj7.jpg < I am not sure about it but this is a screenshoot of working processes and usages.

Comment: Oh, you're firing it from controller. I missed that. Your php-fpm kills it because your artisan call is not async. Try using queues for async jobs.

Comment: I've just tried jobs/queues, and it is still stopped in middle of the script...

Comment: It's possible that even though you're using a job/queue, you don't have proper queueing system set up and your queue driver is `sync` which, you guessed it, runs all queue items synchronously, just like calling the artisan command. So it'll have the same killing issues. If you think this is the case, try setting up a proper queue and a CLI-based queue listener and see what happens. You can use your database to run a queue if you don't have something like beanstalk or ironmq, etc. set up.

Comment: I'd tried to modify the config file with request_terminate_timeout = 0 but stills the same problem. And we're using reddis as a queue-driver, is that ok ?